# Gmail login issue through real device for flutter android app

Tags: flutter, gmail

Getting this error while try to gmail login on flutter android app through real device.

**EGLNativeWindowType 0x7902319310 disconnect failed**

What actually happen:

- click login option with gamil
- pop up for selecting gmail credential to login
- after selection of gmail credential, blink the window and show this error on console

Answer (score 0):

1- Connect your project with Firebase.

2- Click on the Sign-in method tab from the Authentication section.

3- Select the option to connect with Google. (Also make sure you enter your SHA-1 Key and mail while installing the SDK)

Then if you are using a state management method like provider, you can try it like this.

```
Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    if(googleUser != null) {
      // Obtain the auth details from the request
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
      await googleUser.authentication;

      // Create a new credential
      final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
      UserCredential userCredential =
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      return userCredential.user;
    }
    else{
      return null;
    }
  }
```

You can also review the documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth